# How can someone else connect to my server. Minecraft 1.10.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I downloaded the Minecraft 1.10.2 server program from the official Minecraft website. I followed the top video on YouTube on how to setup a server.  I did everything I was supposed to do (with port forwarding and stuff like that) but only people connected to my internet can join. I want to fix that so I don't have to pay for a realm (also I didn't use the Hamachi).

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup port forwarding for port 25565 in your router/firewall. Otherwise nobody from the other side of your router can join.

If you changed the port you need of course forward the one you used.

Answer (score 0):

First press "Open to Lan". Then choose one of the options below:

---

Option 1)

Invite your friend to come to your home. Use the same router, and your computer will appear in your friends' multiplayer menu.

---

Option 2)

Download [LogMeIn Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net) and connect to the same room.

---

Option 3)

Pretty complex option. Not suggested if you don't know what to do!

When you press "Open to Lan" minecraft should say: Server hosted in port XXXXX

Go to Router settings and open that port.